# How can I pass credential to coginto by using url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I deploy a backend sitting behind application load balancer in AWS. Cognito user pool is used to authenticate the request. When I open the ALB url, below screen will popup to ask me input username and password. After that, it will redirect to my backend url.

My question is how I can pass the credential in the url so that it doesn't prompt the cognito popup dialog?

e.g. my alb url is `http://www.mytest.com`, I'd like to make it work by passing the url `http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@www.mytest.com`. How can I make cognito accept this request?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Not only is it impossible in cognito, most browsers have dropped support for this feature due to security concerns.

Comment: The reason I am asking that is to use this url in a backend application not browser.

Comment: Why do you need url in backend when you can use SDK and pass credentials?

Comment: I have a ALB sitting behind cognito and I need to call the ALB from kinesis firehose directly. That's why i am looking for passing the credential via url.

Comment: It is not possible sorry. You'll need to create your own API which reads values from URL and returns token